# Insert filename and line number into stage for Json Format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have copy command

Table structure :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE transient TABLE PB_INVEOR_JSON_2 (
  var variant ,
   file_name text,
  line_number number
 
);
```

My Copy command:

```
 copy into PB_INVEOR_JSON_2(VAR,FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER) 
  from (select $1,metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number @investor_stage_s3/EMBRO_20220111/ )
  pattern='.*Investor_.*.json' 
  FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE= 'JSON' strip_outer_array=true)
  on_error=continue FORCE = TRUE
```

I am unable to get this insert. Can some one guide me to get filename.

Ideally I would like PB_INVEOR_JSON_2  table in this format

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
| METADATA$FILENAME | METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER | PARSE_JSON($1) |
|-------------------+--------------------------+----------------|
| s3://em/a/a.json  | 1                        | {              |
|                   |                          |   "a": {       |
|                   |                          |     "b": "x1", |
|                   |                          |     "c": "y1"  |
|                   |                          |   }            |
|                   |                          | }              |
| s3://em/a/a.json. |    2                     | {              |
|                   |                          |   "a": {       |
|                   |                          |     "b": "x2", |
|                   |                          |     "c": "y2"  |
|                   |                          |   }            |
|                   |                          | }              |
+-------------------+--------------------------+----------------+
```

Error:

SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 62 unexpected '@investor_stage_s3/EMBRO_20220111/'.

Comment: Can you include the error message that you are receiving and possibly the DDL of the table that you are trying to insert the data into?  First glance, you're missing a FROM in your COPY INTO statement, but not sure if that is just an issue with how the question was posted on Stackoverflow.

Comment: "from" is there in the statement

Comment: Added my snowflake error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing the FROM in the SELECT portion of the COPY statement:

```
copy into PB_INVEOR_JSON_2(VAR,FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER) 
  from (
      select $1,metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number
      from @investor_stage_s3/EMBRO_20220111/ 
)
  pattern='.*Investor_.*.json' 
  FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE= 'JSON' strip_outer_array=true)
  on_error=continue FORCE = TRUE
```

Comment: Got it Thank You